# Azure pipelines - system.debug variable overriden

Tags: azure-devops, architecture, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to reference a task in an external yaml file and run it if debug mode is on (system diagnostics checkbox selected, which makes system.debug=true).

I tried the following lines of code:

```
- ${{ if eq(variables['system.debug'],true) }}:
  - template: ./steps/devops/print-directory.yaml
    parameters:
    displayName: "[Debug] List Pipeline Workspace files"
    folder: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
```

Somehow the system.debug variable is emptied before it enters that condition, and so the task is not exhibited during pipeline execution.

Is there a way of keeping the value of system.debug variable so that it enters the condition? Is there another way to access this variable, or address this problem ?

I've tried to declare a variable called system.debug in the pipeline:

```
variables:
  - name: system.debug
    value: true
```

And in this case, the task was correctly exhibited in the pipeline execution, which proves that the system variable is emptied at some point of the pipeline !

Comment: Try `eq(variables['system.debug'],'true')`. Variables are not typed, they are all strings. `eq` *should* coerce strings to appropriate types, but I've never had good luck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. `${{ }}` is a compile-time expression and `system.debug` is set at runtime.

Take a look [here on Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/systemdebug-variable-seems-to-evaluate-to-null-whe/862950#TPIN-N878852)

> Runtime variables cannot be referenced from template expressions ( inside ${{ }}). Only variables defined within the YAML can be used there. This is not a behavior change. Runtime variables like `system.debug` can be used in expressions within the condition attribute of step however.